# Auto date calculator in excel based on different conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, macros

I have an excel sheet with an auto date calculator function linked to each cells. 
I want this function to work based on different condition. For eg: (lets say there are two conditions A and B)for condition A (I will put A in A1 cell), I want the date function to be [DATE(YEAR(B2), MONTH(B2), DAY(B2)+5)] and for condition B (I will put B in A2 cell), I want the date function to be [DATE(YEAR(B2), MONTH(B2), DAY(B2)+10)]. 
Is this possible to do in excel on one sheet based on whichever condition I enter?
Thanks a lot.

Nupur

Answer (score 0):

From your description, A and B are not necessarily mutually exclusive as you are putting them in different cells. So it is not clear what should happen if A1=A and A2=B.
If you meant them both to be in A1 then:

```
=IF(A1="A",DATE(YEAR(B2), MONTH(B2), DAY(B2)+5), IF(A1="B",DATE(YEAR(B2), MONTH(B2), DAY(B2)+10),""),"")
```

However, you don't really need all that DATE(...) stuff, since you can just add numbers to dates like this:

```
=IF(A1="A",B2+5),IF(A1="B",B2+10),""),"")
```